# How do I add ground truth in FEBRL

Tags: named-entity-recognition

I'm using [FEBRL](http://crpit.com/confpapers/CRPITV80Christen.pdf) to do some entity resolution, but I can't figure out a way to add the ground truth to the program in order to evaluate the results.

Can someone with experience on this program help me on this?

[(download link to FEBRL)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/febrl/)